# How does one match alphabets of different languages in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, non-ascii-characters

How to find sequence of Alphabets of non-ASCII (other languages) in a given string in PostgreSQL? For example, ASCII alphabets can be matched using '[A-Za-z]'.

In SQL Server, @ch BETWEEN 'A' and 'Z' matches the characters like Ñ, ü, Ä, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the collation you are using. With most natural language collations, the comparison would work:

```
SELECT 'ñ' COLLATE "en-US-x-icu" BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z';

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)
```

The easiest way to check if a string contains only alphabetic characters is a regular expression:

```
SELECT NOT '中文µxY' COLLATE "de_AT.utf8" ~ '[^[:alpha:]]';

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)

SELECT NOT 'a+b' COLLATE "de_AT.utf8" ~ '[^[:alpha:]]';

 ?column? 
══════════
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: The point is that how does one check for alphabets in all the other collations. Note that I am looking for non-ASCII Alphabets.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer provides. If you need something else, please explain the difference.

Comment: Thanks and sincere apologies @laurenz-albe for the solution and not understanding it respectively. I kind of understand the concept now. However, the second set of statements give an error that the collation "de_AT.utf8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist. Please help me that, if possible.

Comment: PostgreSQL uses the collations provided by the operating system, so they might be different on your system. Look at `pg_collation` and pick one of the natural language collations.

Comment: For understanding collation in PostgreSQL, 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94887 is helpful !!!

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL Regular expressions and character classes can be used to match non-ASCII alphabets in a given string. Try running the following query to extract rows from your table where one or more characters from the non-ASCII alphabet are present in the 'your_column'. For your particular case, change the table and column names as necessary.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column ~ '\p{L}';
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: It throws Error "bad escape sequence".

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql one can use regular expression to find the sequence of non -ASCII alphabets.The `[^[:ascii:]]`pattern matches any character that is not in the ASCII character set and it can be done as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column ~ '[^[:ascii:]]';
```

Comment: But it will give all the non-ascii characters, but I am looking for only alphabets only!!!